# Generating a dataframe using a collection of JSON objects from a file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a log file where every line is a log record such as:

`{"log":{"identifier": "x", "message": {"key" : "value"}}}`

What I'd like to do is convert this JSON collection to a single DataFrame for analysis.
Example

```
identifier  |    key
------------|-------------
    x       |   value
```

Up till now, I have done the following

```py
     with open("../data/cleaned_logs_xs.json", 'r') as logfile:
        for line in logfile:
            jsonified = json.loads(line)
            log = jsonified["log"]
            df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(log)
            df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.split(".")[-1])
```

Read this file line by line, convert every single record to a DataFrame and append the DataFrame to a parent DataFrame. At the end of this loop, it builds the final DataFrame I need.

Now I know this is extremely hack-y and inefficient. What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At this moment, I've removed the constant appending to the parent dataframe.
I append the JSON encoded log message into an array through a loop and at the end convert the array of JSON records to a dataframe using the following:

```py
   log_messages = list()
   for line in logfile:
       jsonified = json.loads(line)
       log = jsonified["log"]
       log_messages.append(log)
   log_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(log_messages)
```

Can this be optimized further?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly if this is what you want but there is something like this:

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

my_json = '{"log": {"identifier": "x", "message": {"key": "value"}}}'
data = json.loads(my_json)
data = json_normalize(data)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
  log.identifier log.message.key
0              x           value
```

In your case just read the json file.

Comment: If you see the question, I've stated there are *multiple* JSON objects I need in one DataFrame. This solution takes a JSON string and converts it to a dataframe, no different to what I have done now.